# Find triplets from an array such that i<j<k, A[i]<A[j]<A[k] and B[i]+B[j]+B[k] is maximum

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

There are two arrays A and B. I need to find sum of triplet in B with three conditions :-

1. i<j<k (where i j and k are indexes)
2. A[i]<A[j]<A[k]
3. B[i]+B[j]+B[k] is maximum

I have tried this question but I can not find a way to optimize it. The time complexity that I am getting is o(n<sup>3</sup>). I need to find the solution so that it is less than o(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: What's your o(n³) solution? That's already better than the simple O(n³) solution.

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward and slightly faster solution runs in O(n ^ 2). For each "middle" index j, find i such that A[i] < A[j] maximizing B[i], and find k such that A[j] < A[k] maximizing B[k]. These can both be found in one pass over possible indices.

It should be possible to speed this up more by preprocessing the input arrays. As it stands, this solution is still better than O(n ^ 3).

Comment: A possible improvement: If we have `x, y` where `x > y` and `A[x] > A[y]` and `B[x] <= B[y]`, then `x` will never be the leftmost index in any `(i, j, k)`, since `B[y]` can always replace `B[x]` to increase (or keep the same) the sum `B[i] + B[j] + B[k]`. So, scan through `A[0..N-1]`, and only keep all `A[x]` where there is no `y` where `y < x` and `A[y] < A[x]` and `B[x] <= B[y]`. Do the same for suffices of `A`. This **monotonic stack** idea should allow a **`O(NlogN)`** solution, if I haven't messed up in my logic.